# How to render an image taken from WebAPI in angular 2

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api

I am fetching an image from a folder in a WebApi and trying to render it in my angular application. This is the web service code in getting the image from its folder:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("GetProfileImage")]
[Authorize]
public IActionResult GetImage()
{
    try
    {
        var userId = User.Claims.First(c => c.Type == "UserID").Value;
        var photo = _applicationContext.files.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserId == userId);
        var fileName = photo.FileName;
        var uploadFilesPath = Path.Combine(_iHostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath, "uploads");
        var filePath = Path.Combine(uploadFilesPath, fileName);

        return Ok(PhysicalFile(filePath, "image/jpeg"));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return BadRequest(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

and this is the code in the backend to call the webapi:

**component.ts**

```
getProfileImage() {
    this.userService.getProfileImage()
        .subscribe((data: any) => {
        this.imageUrl = data.fileName;
        console.log(data.fileName);
  });
}
```

**service.ts**

```
public getProfileImage = () => {
    return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + '/api/ApplicationUser/GetProfileImage');
}
```

**component.html**

```
<div class="card-avatar" *ngIf="imageUrl">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" >
        <img class="img" src="imageUrl" />
    </a>
</div>
```

When I console.log the reply, I get the physical location of the file itself like so:

> D:\backend\uploads\ca897a19-d8f6-4f77-8445-927c29f9f86d.jpg

but it is not rendering in my src in the .html file.

Can you please show me how to do it right. Thank you.

Comment: You could also just have the src point to the action ie `this.baseUrl + '/api/ApplicationUser/GetProfileImage'` and have it return the raw data for the image tag to render

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
<img class="img" [src]="imageUrl" />
```

or

```
<img class="img" src="{{imageUrl}}" />
```

Comment: Thank you  for pointing that out. Unfortunately, it didn't resolve my issue. I just converted it to bytes and added 'data:image/jpeg;base64'

Comment: Yes. That's another  way to do it

Answer (score 1):

Have the action return the raw image data when called

```
//GET api/ApplicationUser/ProfileImage
[HttpGet("ProfileImage")]
[Authorize]
public IActionResult GetImage() {
    try {
        var userId = User.Claims.First(c => c.Type == "UserID").Value;
        var photo = _applicationContext.files.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserId == userId);

        if(photo == null) return NotFound();

        var fileName = photo.FileName;
        var uploadFilesPath = Path.Combine(_iHostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath, "uploads");
        var filePath = Path.Combine(uploadFilesPath, fileName);

        if(!System.IO.File.Exists(filePath)) return NotFound();

        return File(filePath, profile.jpg, "image/jpeg"));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return BadRequest(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

And just have the component call the action using it's route/URL.

*component.ts*

```
getProfileImage() {
    this.imageUrl = this.userService.getProfileImage();
    console.log(this.imageUrl);
}
```

*service.ts*

```
public getProfileImage = () => {
    return this.baseUrl + '/api/ApplicationUser/ProfileImage';
}
```

*component.html*

```
<div class="card-avatar" *ngIf="imageUrl">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" >
        <img class="img" src="{{imageUrl}}" />
    </a>
</div>
```

The browser should handle the actual download and rendering of the image as it was designed to when it parses the `img.src` path.

Answer (score 0):

**component.html**

```
<div class="card-avatar" *ngIf="imageUrl">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" >
        <img class="img" src="{{imageUrl}}" />
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Please help fighting the misconception that StackOverflow is a free code writing service, by augmenting your code-only answer with some explanation. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/23308211)

Answer (score 0):

You can Always convert image on Base64 and embed it over html . For refrence you can see 
ngx-webcam